# Did France ban wifi in schools and daycares in 2015 because of health concerns?

Tags: public-health, france, wifi

A [variety](https://www.emfhome.com/news/wifi-health-school) of [websites](https://www.powerwatch.org.uk/news/2015-02-05-france-wifi-restrictions.asp) (along with many claims on social media sites like [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/CwGW3q8A2A6/)) [claim](https://parenting.firstcry.com/articles/the-shocking-reason-france-banned-wi-fi-in-schools/) a law that went into effect in January 2015 bans wifi in schools and nurseries for health reasons.

[One](https://ehtrust.org/france-new-national-law-bans-wifi-nursery-school/) links to the [statute](https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/14/ta/ta0468.asp), but I have no French comprehension skills.

This is a two-part question:

1. Does the ordinance passed match the claims made about it?
2. Have any ordinances passed *since* the ban, if it is one, reversed the 2015 statute and/or disproven its claims (if it were made because of health concerns)?

Comment: [This site](https://radiasmart.com/blog/france-bans-wifi-in-kindergartens-childcare/) adds: *"A number of schools in England, France and Canada have dismantled their Wi-Fi and reverted to a wired system due to concerns raised by parents and teachers, and also due to health symptoms experienced by some children. In other countries, like Switzerland, Italy, Austria, Luxembourg, Bulgaria, Poland, Hungary, Israel, Russia and China, decisions have been made to lower the legal exposure limit when it comes to electromagnetic wave radiation, especially in areas where children are spending time."*

Comment: @WeatherVane - that site is also suspiciously lacking in sources: "one study suggest that limiting children's exposure to WIFI radiation is absolutely a smart move, as children and fetuses absorb more microwave radiation. This, according to the authors, is because their bodies are relatively smaller, their skulls are thinner, and their brain tissue is more absorbent than in an adult." If that were on Wikipedia, it would get tagged "what study?"

Comment: I think it's important to note here that _"due to concerns raised by parents and teachers"_ is not the same as _"health reasons"_, since a school could do pretty much any arbitrary thing to please the parents even though the school board doesn't find it to be a health issue. Maybe that's the root of the claim?

Comment: Is the question "Is wifi considered harmful?" or is it "Is the law cited about a ban on wifi?" or is it "Was it because wifi is dangerous?" The question title needs clarifying: it contains a classic ambiguity.

Comment: @WeatherVane - how is the question a "classic ambiguity"? It is clearly asking if the ban was for health reasons.

Comment: @warren so, to be extra clear, you are NOT asking about the validity of the health reasons, ONLY if they are the stated motivation for the law.

Comment: @thelr - I'm asking *precisely* what the question asks: was the ban put in place for "health reasons". There is no doubt the ban exist[ed|s]. I do not know why this seems so complicated :)

Answer (score 23):

*EDIT: Used much more explicit reference to health concerns in the discussions made which led to the statute.*

**Has Wifi been banned in schools/daycares?**

Wifi has only been banned in some cases, specifically spaces that take care of children 3 years or less. The relevant article from the [statute](https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/14/ta/ta0468.asp) is the following:

> Article 7
>
> I. – Dans les établissements mentionnés au chapitre IV du titre II du
> livre III de la deuxième partie du code de la santé publique,
> l’installation d’un équipement terminal fixe équipé d’un accès sans
> fil à internet est interdite dans les espaces dédiés à l’accueil, au
> repos et aux activités des enfants de moins de trois ans.
>
> II. – Dans les classes des écoles primaires, les accès sans fil des
> équipements mentionnés à l’article 184 de la loi n° 2010-788 du 12
> juillet 2010 portant engagement national pour l’environnement
> installés après la publication de la présente loi sont désactivés
> lorsqu’ils ne sont pas utilisés pour les activités numériques
> pédagogiques.
>
> III. – Dans les écoles primaires, toute nouvelle installation d’un
> réseau radioélectrique fait l’objet d’une information préalable du
> conseil d’école.

In particular the first bullet point states that wireless equipment may not be used in spaces dedicated to welcoming children less than 3 years old.

The second bullet point requires said equipment to be deactivated when not in use. (specifying that it is for educational purposes)

**Was the ban done due to health risk concerns?**

Yes, as seen from this document summing up some of the discussions done in the *[Assemblée Nationale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Assembly_(France))*:

> Comme votre rapporteure l’indiquait l’an passé, le Parlement est en
> effet confronté à un enjeu majeur : légiférer en situation
> d’incertitude scientifique. **S’il n’appartient pas à la représentation
> nationale de décider de l’existence d’un lien entre l’exposition aux
> ondes électromagnétiques et les risques sanitaires, il est de sa
> responsabilité de moderniser le cadre juridique applicable pour
> prévenir la survenance d’un drame sanitaire**, répondre aux inquiétudes
> de nos concitoyens et assurer le respect des principes
> constitutionnels de notre pays, au premier rang desquels celui de
> vivre dans un environnement équilibré et respectueux de la santé.

Translation mine below:

> [As previously mentioned] the past year, the [Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Parliament) is facing a
> major issue: to legislate in a context of scientific uncertainty.
> **While it is not up to the national representation to decide on the existence of a link between exposure to electromagnetic waves and health risks,
> it is its responsibility to modernize the applicable legal framework
> to prevent such risks from occuring**, to provide an answer to the
> worries of our citizens and ensure the respect of the constitutional
> ideals of our country, chief among them being to live in a stable
> environment that remains respectful of health.

**Has the law been reversed since then?**

Not from what I have found.

[This article](https://www.ac-paris.fr/wifi-quelles-precautions-prendre-dans-les-etablissements-scolaires-125673) (February 2023) directly links to the law that went into effect in 2015, as does [this document](https://eduscol.education.fr/document/20998/download) (May 2023) on Wifi usage in school-related contexts.

Comment: Nota: in the statute, article 8 points that a report shall be made by the government regarding EHS (Electromagnetic HyperSensibility). I initially included it in the answer but removed it as it didn't appear to be particularly related to Wifi usage in spaces dedicated to children 3 years or less. For other cases, the question has already been tackled here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28403/does-electromagnetic-hypersensitivity-ehs-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: [Current version of that law](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/id/JORFTEXT000030212642). No changes since the original version in 2015. Note that Article 7 does not forbid Wi-Fi coverage, or even the use of mobile Wi-Fi devices in general. It only forbids **fixed** devices from using Wi-Fi, and Wi-Fi should be turned off only on specific mobile devices when not used for educational purposes. Its scope is thus quite limited in this respect. The principal impact of this law is the obligation to provide (wired) headsets with mobile phones (in theory only on request for minors under 14).